# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, aws, reactjs

こちらのサイトを参考にReact.jsを用いてS3のリストを取得するスクリプトを作成しております。
https://note.kiriukun.com/entry/20190419-s3-examples-list-objects-in-node

npm startで先ほど動作を確認したところ、タイトルのエラーに引っかかってしまい、直せない状況です。
App.jsの内容は以下の通りです。
JavaScriptはあまり触ってこなかったので初歩的な質問となっているかもしれませんが、どうぞ宜しくお願い致します。

````
import Amplify, { Storage } from 'aws-amplify';
import { AmplifyAuthenticator, AmplifySignUp, AmplifySignOut } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';
import { AuthState, onAuthUIStateChange } from '@aws-amplify/ui-components';
import awsconfig from './aws-exports';
import aws from 'aws-sdk';
import { Bucket } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';

Amplify.configure(awsconfig);

const App = () => {
    const [name, setName] = useState('')
    const [file, setFile] = useState('')
    const [response, setResponse] = useState('')

    const [authState, setAuthState] = React.useState();
    const [user, setUser] = React.useState();

    React.useEffect(() => {
        return onAuthUIStateChange((nextAuthState, authData) => {
            setAuthState(nextAuthState);
            setUser(authData)
        });
    }, []);

    const onChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    if (e.target.files[0] !== null) {
      setFile(e.target.files[0])
      setName(e.target.files[0].name)
    }
  }

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    if (file) {
      Storage.put(name, file, {
        /* level: 'protected', */
        contentType: file.type,
      })
        .then((result) => {
          console.log(result)
          setResponse(`Success uploading file: ${name}!`)
        })
        .then(() => {
          document.getElementById('file-input').value = null
          setFile(null)
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err)
          setResponse(`Can't upload file: ${err}`)
        })
    } else {
      setResponse(`Files needed!`)
    }
  }

  aws.config.update({   
    region: 'ap-northeast-1',  // ここでは東京リージョンを入力
  });
  var s3 = new aws.S3();
  let keyList = [];
    for (let continuationToken = null;;) {
        // パラメータ作成
        const params = {
            Bucket: 'sample',  // バケット名
        };
        if (continuationToken) {
            // 読み込み開始位置 (ContinuationToken) がある場合はパラメータに追加
            params.ContinuationToken = continuationToken;
        }
        
        // オブジェクトのリストを取得
        const res = s3.listObjectsV2(params).promise();
        
        // オブジェクトキー (Key属性) だけ取り出してキーリストに追加
        res.Contents.map(v => v.Key).forEach(v => {
            keyList.push(v);
        });
        
        // listObjectsV2 が一度に取得できるのは1000件まで
        // リストが切り詰められている場合は IsTruncated がtrueになる
        if (!res.IsTruncated) {
            break;
        }
        
        // 次の読み込み開始位置を保存
        continuationToken = res.NextContinuationToken;
    }
    
    // 全てのオブジェクトを処理
    for (let key of keyList) {
        // オブジェクトを取得
        const res = s3.getObject({
            Bucket: 'sample',
            Key: key
        }).promise();
        
        // ファイル本文 (Buffer) をUTF-8でデコード
        const body = res.Body.toString('utf8');
        
        // 1行目だけコンソールに出力
        console.log(key + ' ->', body.split('\n')[0].trim());
    }

  return authState === AuthState.SignedIn && user ? (
      <div className="App">
          <div>Hello, {user.username}</div>
          <div className='video-uploader'>
            <form onSubmit={(e) => onSubmit(e)}>
            <p>
              <label className='select-label'>Select video: </label>
            </p>
            <p>
              <input
                className='video-input'
                type='file'
                id='file-input'
                accept='image/*, video/*'
                onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
              />
            </p>
            <button type='submit' className='btn'>Submit</button>
          </form>
          </div>
          <AmplifySignOut />
      </div>
    ) : (
      <AmplifyAuthenticator>
        <AmplifySignUp
          slot="sign-up"
          formFields={[
            { type: "username" },
            { type: "password" },
            { type: "email" }
          ]}
        />
      </AmplifyAuthenticator>
  );
}

export default App;```
````

Comment: [こちら](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#listObjectsV2-property)を参考にエラーのキャッチをしてしてみて、何かしらエラーが出ていないか確認できますか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const res = s3.listObjectsV2(params).promise();
        
// オブジェクトキー (Key属性) だけ取り出してキーリストに追加
res.Contents.map(v => v.Key).forEach(v => {
     keyList.push(v);
});
```

resは正常な値が取得できてないから、res.Contentsも存在しないか予想のlistやarrayではないため、res.Contents.mapを使うと、「Cannot read property 'map' of undefined」が出るはずです。

リンク元のコードは

```
const res = await s3.listObjectsV2(params).promise();
```

だけど、結果を取得完了するまでに待つために、awaitは省略しないように試してみてください。